# Adding int to short

Tags: java

A colleague of mine asked this question to me and I am kind of confused.

```
int i = 123456;
short x = 12;
```

The statement

```
x += i;
```

Compiles fine however

```
x = x + i;
```

doesn't

What is Java doing here?

Comment: You are trying to add int to short however. a = b != b = a

Comment: You are actually adding an int to a short

Comment: For interest try this `char ch = '0'; ch *= 1.2;` now ch is `'8'` ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int i = 123456;
short x = 12;
x += i;
```

is actually

```
int i = 123456;
short x = 12;
x = (short)(x + i);
```

Whereas `x = x + i` is simply `x = x + i`. It does not automatically cast as a `short` and hence causes the error (`x + i` is of type `int`).

---

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.
>
> <sub>- [**JLS §15.26.2**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator of integral types (int, short, char and byte) always returns an int as result.

You can see that with this code:

```
//char x = 0;
//short x = 0;
//byte x = 0;
int x = 0;
x = x + x;
```

It won't compile unless `x` is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are treated as `int` unless you specifically cast them otherwise.  So in the second statement when you use a literal number instead of a variable, it doesn't automatically cast it to the appropriate type.

```
x = x + (short)1;
```

...should work.

Comment: I wrote wrong equation. I updated my question. See its `x = x + i`.

Comment: Ok, then why doesn't x = x + x; work? The problem isn`t on the number 1 but on the + operator that returns an int.