# In C: what does var = x | y | z; mean?

Tags: c

So I've recently started working with TI's CC2650 device and am trying to learn how to program it by studying some of their sample applications. I see a lot of variables declared in this format and I have no clue what it means:

```
var1 = x | y | z;
```

In the example above, `var1` is of type uint8_t.

Comment: I wasn't even aware it was a C logical operator. so I didn't even know to google that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java | operator with integers;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640933/java-operator-with-integers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|` is the binary bitwise `or` operator. For example: `0x00ff | 0xff00` is `0xffff`.

Answer (score 5):

bitwise OR operator, so if you have x = 5 (101) y = 8 (1000) and z = 20 (10100), values in parenthesis are binary values so
`x | y | z = 101 | 1000 | 10100 = 11101`

Answer (score 1):

The operator `|` in C is known a s [bitwise *OR* operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx). Similar to other bitwise operators (say *AND* `&`), bitwise *OR* only operates at the bit level. Its result is a `1` if one of the either bits is `1` and zero only when both bits are `0`. The `|` which can be called a pipe! Look at the following:

```
bit a   bit b   a | b (a OR b)
   0       0       0
   0       1       1
   1       0       1
   1       1       1
```

In the expression, you mentioned:

```
var1 = x | y | z | ...;
```

as there are many `|` in a single statement, you have to know that, bitwise *OR* operator has [Left-to-right Associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) means the operations are grouped from the left. Hence the above expression would be interpreted as:

```
var1 = (x | y) | z | ...
=> var1 = ((x | y) | z) | ...
....
```

Read more about Associativity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589257/what-does-left-to-right-associativity-mean).

Comment: I think it might be better to say that the operation `or` is a symmetric (commutative) and is both left and right associative.

Comment: @M.Shaw, don't messed with logical _OR_ `||` and bitwise _OR_ `|`.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the 2nd part - but the operation is still commutative and both left and right associative.

Comment: @M.Shaw, take a look [Group 11 precedence, left to right associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx).

Comment: It is a design choice (or perhaps arbitrary) to decide that it is left-to-right associative. It is quite obvious that `a | b == b | a` and `(a | b) | c == a | (b | c)` for any `a,b,c`. If the compiler.