# What is mean 'return a|b|c' in the non void java function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new at java, and I'm a little confused by the functions '|' in non void java functions return

```
private int donUnderstand() {
    return 1 | 2 | 3 | 4; //return 7, where is 7 come from?
}
```

Function above will return 7, but I don't get it where is 7 come from. I need some explanation. What is '|' character really mean at that function?

Comment: It's "bitwise OR" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295469/what-does-mean-pipe-equal-operator

Comment: I really hope this is not a method found in a real application...

Answer (score 6):

`|` is the [bitwise OR operator in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-java/). 
In your example, it ORs together  `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. Their binary representation is `0001`, `0010`, `0011` and `0100`, respectively. This results in `0111`, which is the binary representation of `7`.

```
1 == 0001
2 == 0010
3 == 0011
4 == 0100
----------- OR
7 == 0111
```

Comment: no worries, I don't gain anything from it either way, just thought it would make more sense like this

Comment: Thanks for the help though, tried to reapply your edits and make it work with mine

Answer (score 0):

| is the bitwise OR operator. That is it would do an OR operation on each bit of the numbers and return the result.
For example:

```
a = 5 = 0101 (In Binary)

b = 7 = 0111 (In Binary)

Bitwise OR Operation of 5 and 7

 0101

| 0111
 ________
  0111  = 7 (In decimal)
```

More info here: [Bitwise OR](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-java/)