# What does "|=" mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm trying to implement the following pseudocode:

[image]

But I fail to understand what the line

```
state_val |= (c(s) == True) << i++
```

does. To give some context, this pseudocode is found in [this](http://www.bradhayes.info/papers/hri17.pdf) paper from MIT, and `c(s)` is an operation that returns `True` or `False` based on `s`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "|=" mean? (pipe equal operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295469/what-does-mean-pipe-equal-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a |= b` means that `a` will be set to the bitwise OR of `a` and `b`. Essentially, `state_val` is a number whose bits represent booleans, and its binary representation will look something like this:

`c7(s) c6(s) c5(s) c4(s) c3(s) c2(s) c1(s) c0(s)`

Where `c0` is the first `c`, `c1` is the second, etc. If `c7(s)`, `c5(s)`, and `c1(s)` were true, then `state_val` would be `10100010` in binary or `162`.

Answer (score 1):

It's bitwise OR. Basically shorthand for

```
state_val = state_val | ((c(s) == True) << i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, and what does the `((c(s) == True) << i++` part do exactly

Comment: i++ -> increment; c(s) == True -> check if score is true; value << number - bitshift number times

Comment: and why is it not in a seperate line? i'm not sure what the `<<` is doing

Comment: @ThomasW Left shift. If `c(s)` is true, then it's `1 << i++`, otherwise `0`. It's like `1 * 2**i++` (two to the power of `i`, increment `i`)

Comment: it's quite common syntax, once you are familiar with that it's easier to read